# Problema para enviar datos de mysql a control select en jsp usando servlet

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp, servlets

**Estimados,** 
Estoy intentando enviar los datos de una consulta sql a un control select de html usando jsp y servlet y ajax, el problema que al enviar los datos por ajax, no me trae el combo box con los datos y la consola tampoco me arroja error, solo me dice conexión exitosa y grave.

Tengo una consulta sql que muestra unos datos a travez de un parametro en la clase FoliosDao.
el parametro es el rut, a traves de dicho parametro obtengo los datos de mysql.
En el servlet llamo a la clase FoliosDao para acceder al metodo y asi tomar los datos. el parametro lo envio desde el formulario jsp utilizando ajax.
Al presionar el botón , el sistema no muestra el resultado, y tampoco me muestra errores en la consola y tampoco en netbeans.
por favor su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código.

Función ajax

```
<script>
  function mostrarFoliosReporteFoliosAjax()
{
    var rutUserAjax= $("#rutUsuarioAjax").val();


            $.ajax({
            url:"reporteFoliosVerFoliosAjaxServlet.do",
            data:{
                rutUserJS : rutUserAjax
            },
            success: function( result ) {
            $("#listaFoliosPorRut").html( result);
            }

    });
}

</script>
```

Formulario con botón

```
<form method="POST">
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Rut :</th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="container-fluid" id="idRutComp">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rutUsuarioAjax">
                                                        </div>

                                                    </td>

                                                    <td><div class="container-fluid">

                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrarFoliosReporteFoliosAjax()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Generar</button>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

                                            <hr>

                                            </form>
```

Contenedor div donde debería mostrase el resultado

```
<div  id="listaFoliosPorRut"></div>
```

Clase Servlet

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


    Folio fl=new Folio();
    Usuario rutUs = new Usuario();

    FoliosDao fodao=new FoliosDao();

try  { 
    Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
    rutUs.setRutPersona(request.getParameter("rutUserJS"));

    ResultSet res=(ResultSet)fodao.listarFoliosReporteReservasPorRut(rutUs);
    ArrayList<Folio> numeroFolio = new ArrayList<Folio>();

    if(res==null)
    {
        String error="No se encontraron datos";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);

    }

    else
    {

            while(res.next())
            {
                numeroFolio.add(new Folio(res.getInt("cod_seq_awb"),res.getString("awb")));
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("numeroFolio", numeroFolio);
            ArrayList<Folio> foli = (ArrayList<Folio>)request.getSession().getAttribute("numeroFolio");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();



                try {


                            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                            out.println("<html>");
                            out.println("<head>");         
                            out.println("</head>");
                            out.println("<body>");


                            out.println("<select class='form-control' name='txt_awbs'>");
                            out.println("<option>Seleccione Folio</option>");
                            for(int i=0; i<foli.size(); i++)
                            {
                                out.println("<option>"+foli.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</option>");
                                //System.out.println("NumeroFolio:"+numeroFolio.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto());
                                                                    System.out.println("Numero de Folio :"+foli.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto());
                            } 

                            out.println("</select>");
                            out.println("</body>");
                            out.println("</html>");   


                } finally {
                    out.close();
                }




    }

}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
    {
            ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Clase metodo de clases FoliosDao

```
    public ResultSet listarFoliosReporteReservasPorRut(Usuario usr)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        String SQL="";

        SQL="select a.cod_seq_awb,a.awb from awb a, rvas r\n" +
            "where a.cod_seq_awb=r.awb_cod_seq_awb"
                + "and r.rut_cliente='"+usr.getRutPersona()+"';";
        res=st.executeQuery(SQL);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FoliosDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda ya que intenté también, mostrandolos en una tabla, pero muestra error 500 en la petición enviada por ajax.

Aquí dejo el código del servlet.

```
 FoliosDao folidao=new FoliosDao();
    Folio fl=new Folio();
    Usuario rutUS=new Usuario();
    rutUS.setRutUsuario(request.getParameter("rutUserJS"));
    ResultSet resultadoF=folidao.listarFoliosReporteReservasPorRut(rutUS);
    //ReservasDao mostrarReservaClienteDao=new ReservasDao();
    //GuiasDao gdaoDisp=new GuiasDao();
    //Usuario usuarioCliente=new Usuario();
    try
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        ArrayList<Folio>numerosFolio=new ArrayList<Folio>();

        if(request.getParameter("rutUserJS").isEmpty())
        {
            String errorFoliosPorRut="No se ingresó datos de entrada";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorFoliosPorRut", errorFoliosPorRut);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("errorVerReservasCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                while(resultadoF.next())
                {
                    //reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS")));
                    numerosFolio.add(new Folio(resultadoF.getInt("cod_seq_awb"),resultadoF.getString("awb")));
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReporteFolioVerFolioAjaxServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("numerosFolio", numerosFolio);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("airExpressClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table class='table-condensed table-hover table-responsive' id='resultado'>");
            out.println("<thead class='input-sm'>");
            out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>N° Folio Completo</th>");


            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println(" </thead>");
            out.println("<tbody class='input-sm'>");


                      try
                      {

                      for(int i=0; i<numerosFolio.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.println("<tr>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+numerosFolio.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</td>");

                                            out.println("<td>"
                                                    + "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    //+ " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAsignarVuelo' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalReservaClienteEliminarReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + "</td>"); 
                                        } 

                      }
                      catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                      {
                          ex.getMessage();
                          out.print("</tr>");
                      }

            out.println("</tbody>");
            out.println("</table>");




        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        }

    }
    catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException nullex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ReporteFolioVerFolioAjaxServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nullex);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola debuguee mi aplicacion y si esta recibiendo un valor null, pero no se cual porque sólo le mando el rut pero al parecer no está llegando.

```
[![Imagen error nullPointer Exception][5]][5]
```

Comment: Creo que en el servlet estás mostrando una página entera (hay html, head, body etc) pero luego, en el js quieres meter todo esto en un div. En el servlet deberías enviar solamente la parte importante - solo lo que está dentro del tag body. Tal como lo tienes el código html resultante se puede cortar dependiendo del navegador.

Comment: Si lo se pero justamente puse el código html completo porque antes solo tenía la etiqueta select y tampoco me funcionaba.

Comment: que otra cosa podría ser lo que no permite mostrar los datos?

Comment: Intenta ir por partes - envía solamente un literal (hola) a ver si se muestra en el div. Luego iremos acotando

Comment: Hola Intenté mostrando los mismos datos de la sesión pero mostrándolos en una tabla , pero se cae con error 500 cuando le paso el rut como parametro

Comment: también intente sólo pasando variables y se muestra por ejemplo si solo recibo el rut en el servlet , puedo verlo, pero si quiero ver los datos de la base de datos usando el rut como parametro , se cae con error 500.

Comment: no se si es error de jquery o de la sesión. por favor su ayuda he intentado muchas formas y he replicado código de otros métodos que si me funcionan, pero no entiendo por qué este no me funciona.

Comment: Debuggea y fíjate donde no fluyen los datos, o ve haciendo print de tus datos en cada paso que haces, desde que recibes datos de la db en tu dao, hasta las operaciones que haces en el controlador. De todos modos java es estricto a trabajar POO, la consulta que haces en el DAO debería ser asignada a un objeto de tipo Entidad y retornar ese/esos objeto(s).

Comment: Acabo de debuguear in me retorna StandardWrapperValve[ReporteFolioVerFolioAjaxServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ReporteFolioVerFolioAjaxServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: el parametro que estoy enviando no lo está recibiendo, sera un problema de la libreria de jquery?

Comment: por favor su ayuda , he intentado de todo y no se que valor esta pasando null